# Rails initialization checksum error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to initialize a new rails app on windows, and running `rails new <appname>` generates everything up to `vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep`, but when `bundle install` is run, rails generates this error:

```
Checksum of /versions does not match the checksum provided by server! Something is wrong.
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, as I've done nothing to rails itself. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: If it's an error caused by windows being finicky, I have the option of moving to Linux, but I'd like to know what's wrong first.

Comment: There is allways an option to move to linux. Install virtualbox. ruby and windows is just pain. you should have more luck with jruby

Comment: jruby is different ruby built on top of the Java Virtual Machine and has nothing to do with linux/windows (jruby runs on both). Using linux or any other *nix is recommended though since you can type along on the console with most decent quality rails learning materials. It can be done with Cygwin  but you still have to remember that you have a bunch of duct tape and popsicles under it and not Posix...

Comment: If you have the option - do move to Linux, you'll save yourself a month..

Comment: Sounds like an issue with bundler and gems, not Rails - I'd try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and reinstalling all existing gems. FWIW, i develop on Windows and most things work fine for me. There are exceptions, but a bit of googling solves them just fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same issue using windows, and was able to solve it by uninstalling bundler and installing an older version.

```
rails new <appname>
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v 1.9
cd <appname>
bundle install
```

That did it for me!

Comment: This fixed it for me too, but I didn't even had to install an older version. I just uninstalled all versions, then reinstalled the latest

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a *.pre.1 version and I chose to uninstall that particular version and then "bundle install" worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your ruby `cache` folder and then try again. So for example if you are on Linux machine and you are using `rbenv` and say ruby `2.1.5` folder. Your path would be similar to something like (Not sure where on windows ruby is stored):

```
 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/
```

Removing this folder and trying `bundle install` again should resolve the issue.

It will be great, if you move to a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

On windows it's a hell to pay in my 5 years of experience what i have learned is not to mess with (ror) or (rs) in windows. here's a cheeky thing you can do an easy way. I believe you are using github as repo, as a editor you are using sublime if thats is a case open your gemfile you will see [check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2kYj.png)  or 
try to clear cache on your server or update the gems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact error and solved it the following way.  I think you are missing the ruby DevKit being installed.

1. Go here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and download/install the latest 32-bit Ruby version (as of writing this 2.2.4, you will need it for the web-console gem)
2. Make sure to add your ruby\bin folder to your environmental path variable
3. The trick is hidden near the bottom-left of the same page under the "Development Kit" section. You need to download and extract the right one into a permanent location (as of writing this for 32-bit - DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe)
4. After extracting the files, go into the main directory and run "ruby dk.rb init" followed by "ruby dk.rb install" (More information can be found [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit)

That fixed it for me and i can now fully install with no checksum issues

Answer (score 0):

This problem began when i tried to run my app. I wrote `rails s` and the console said me `Could not find sdoc-0.4.1 in any of the sources Run bundle install to install missing gems.` Then i wrote `bundle install` and the message that appeared was `Checksum of /versions does not match the checksum provided by server! Something is wrong.`

I solve this problem following this steps:

1. Wrote `bundle install`
2. The console said me `Could not find sdoc-0.4.1 in any of the sources`
3. Then i reinstalled this gem with `gem install sdoc -v 0.4.1`
4. I tried again to write `rails s` and it's was solved.

`